# How do you move the prefix argument to a different key in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, colemak

I'm using an alternate keyboard layout (Colemak) and I want to move the `universal-argument` command to a different key in Emacs, <kbd>C-l</kbd> instead of <kbd>C-u</kbd>. I tried the following, but it doesn't let me chain multiple universal arguments together multiplicatively (<kbd>C-l C-l C-l</kbd>) and it breaks <kbd>C-l C-u</kbd> too (which should move up 4 lines):

```
(global-set-key "\C-l" 'universal-argument)
(global-set-key "\C-u" 'previous-line)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you use the prefix argument, Emacs uses a keymap temporarily to handle the universal argument functionality.  So, you need to make the changes you've made there too:

```
(define-key universal-argument-map "\C-l" 'universal-argument-more)
(define-key universal-argument-map "\C-u" nil)
```

The first sets up <kbd>C-l</kbd> to be the continuation of `universal-argument`, and the second un-defines the <kbd>C-u</kbd> from that map b/c you no longer want it to be the universal argument.